# Input validation from redirected stdin in C

Tags: c, validation, stdin

I am trying to write a programme in C for an assignment that detects CSV format eg. decimalcommadecimal. and gives a output as to if the file is in the required format or not. I have tried using various inputs from stdin and using isdigit etc. but to no success. I'm a mega noob and have barely done any C programming before, I attempted to use regexc but couldn't figure out the syntax for using it.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
const char EOL = '\n';

int cbreak(void);
int check_dig(void);
int value =1;
char c;

int main()
{

    while((scanf("%c" ,&c)) !=EOF&& value !=0)
    check_dig();

    printf("\n%d\n",value);
}

int check_dig()
{
    if (c == EOL)
        scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c == isdigit)
        scanf("%c", &c);
    else if (c == ',')
        scanf("%c", &c);
    else value = 0;
}
```

Thanks Guys I'm now to this stage but stumped as how to finish, I need to printf either 1 or 0 depending on validation and I want to do this as suggested using a return value.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int check_digit(int);
int check_comma(int);
int skip_char(int);
int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) !=EOF)
        if (check_digit(c))
            skip_char(c);
        else if (check_comma(c))
            skip_char(c);
        else return 0;
}

int check_digit(int c)
{   
    if (isdigit(c))
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}    

int check_comma(int c)
{
    if (c == ',')
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int skip_char(int c)
{
    c = getchar(); // will this skip 2 chars as i have a while loop that has c=getchar()??
    return c;
}
```

Comment: p.s. I'm not looking for a code pasted soulition I want to understand how to solve the problem and what I'm doing wrong thanks.

Comment: I don't think this solves your problem in any way, but you might want to add "return 0;" to the end of your main() function

Comment: What is it that check_digit is expected to accomplish?  At present, if c is EOL, a digit (isdigit should be used as a function: isdigit(c)), or a comma, you read another character, otherwise set value to 0.  I would think you'd want to DO something with c if it were a digit, but since you give no guidance as to what that might be, its kind of hard to help.

Comment: FYI, make sure to convert the tabs in your code to spaces before pasting it into the website.  Tabs throw off the formatting engine and everything comes out indented incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I'd recommend to not use that vast list of globals. Use parameters in functions and return values from functions.

Second `isdigit` does not work like that. It takes a parameter and return true or false. [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/)

Further I'd use [getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/) over scanf.

Your `int check_dig()` function is a bit strange. You keep reading characters inside the function.

I would perhaps do something like:

```
int valid_csv(char c)
{
    if (isdigit(c))
        return 1;
    /* etc. other checks */
    if all fails
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    /* read chars into c and call fun by something like */
    valid_svc(c);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit: As a rule of thumb. A function should do one thing, and one thing only, and do it well. The name of the function should reflect what it does.

---

Edit.2:

You do not need to "skip char". The way it goes, in your new code, is that you skip every other character.

I.e.:

File: 12,33,66,14

In your code you'll get

- c = getchar => c == 1
- c is digit

  - getchar => you read 2 (and never validates it)
- c = getchar => c == ,
- c is comma

  - getchar => you read 3 (and never validates it)
- ...

Further; I know I wrote "a function should do one thing" - but but not that literal. Ie your new `check_digit` is redundant. Use `isdigit` directly. If you have floats in your csv you'll have to expand or use a different approach.

To illustrate by example; easier then writing on here :)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int valid_csv_chr(int);
int valid_csv(); /* guess naming could be better. */

int main(void)
{
    if (valid_csv())
        puts("1");
    else
        puts("0");

    return 0; /* Main should return 0 if there was no "crash" scenario etc.
     * You could also return i.e. 1 if the file is not validated as csv. 
     * Do not think of 1 and 0 as boolean true / false here. */
}

int valid_csv()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) !=EOF) {
        if (!valid_csv_chr(c)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int valid_csv_chr(int c)
{
    if (isdigit(c))
        return 1;
    if (c == ',')
        return 1;
    if (c == '\n')
        return 1;
        /* add checks for space etc. */
    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit.3:

Code structure is something one has to learn just as much as the language itself. It is learning by doing and writing. That one realize that re-structure of code is necessary happens from time to time - but the more one think before writing, make a simple structure at first and expand it, etc. it is more avoidable.

Anyhow; practice, practice, practice. And keep these topics in mind at all time.

Even if it can "look" simple, it is not. I think often books, tutorials, courses etc. have all to little focus on this topic. It is all about `for`, `if`, functions etc. and all to little on how to stitch it all together in a ***good*** way.

There are several advantages of splitting up the code.

- It makes it much more readable.
- It makes it easier to maintain.
- Bugs and errors can often be fixed by fixing a small function rather then a huge one.

  - On some cases I have seen code of thousands of lines where one have some monster functions that is buggy. Fixing by tweaking it is close to impossible and a complete re-write is only option.
- It is easier to optimize a function that does one task, and is not to big.
- It is easier to expand to cover more scenarios when using smaller functions.

  - Say for example in your program. You could change it to "validate data file" covering csv, tab delimited, aligned, etc.

The last point is actually a way I often think of it when writing; "How should I best implement this code so that, if, in the future, I'd like to expand it to cover more scenarios, it can be easily done."

Myself I use [this](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.1/Documentation/CodingStyle) as a ***base*** when writing in C combined with things I've learned in K & R's ANSI C book ++. See for example what is written about [functions](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.1/Documentation/CodingStyle#L344).

Also; being strict on coding style makes it much easier to read and maintain. I use in large part what is described in the document above. It is no *law*, but being conscious about it makes the coding life so much simpler.

Comment: Thanks I see I should have been using a function with sub functions instead of just trying to run it all out of main that makes it a lot simpler. but quite annoying seeing how long i've spent on something so simple... ;-(

Comment: @LachlanMcGivern; added yet another section. And yes, it can be annoying, but rather think of how much you have learned by it. It is an invaluable lesson.

Comment: Thanks it definitly helped now I'm trying the suggested way of using strtok() as another solution, and have read up on pointer in [link](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch1x.htm) and have looked up on stack overflow the problems with segment errors using strtok() and i have checked that i'm using a pointer not a constant but still cant get strtok to work??? still geting a segment error? I might add code to top post

Comment: @LachlanMcGivern I'd suggest you post a new question, if you do not manage to get it to work, rather then exhaust this post any further. It is already over the limit ;)

Comment: ok will do i just didn't want to post if it was something simple but will go through it all again first

Comment: @LachlanMcGivern; Believe I have read somewhere that questions should not change (to much) in context. But I'm not 100% sure. Should be in a FAQ somewhere. Perhaps some pointers at http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using regexc for this problem, especially if you're new to C.  You should be able to solve it using some of the basic standard library features.  You seem to be on the right general track.  You are reading in characters and determining what class they fit in.  Since you know that a valid input consists of only numbers and the comma character, you can immediately terminate the program if you encounter anything that's not one of those two things.  Here are a few tips that might help.

If you're reading a character at a time, `getchar` might prove easier to use than `scanf`.

Also, `isdigit` is a function.  Instead of saying `if (c == isdigit)`, you want to say `if (isdigit(c))`.

Your function `check_dig` is defined to return an `int`, but there is no `return` statement in the function.  The function needs to be modified to return a value, and `main` needs to do something with this value.  A general rule of thumb is that a function returns zero when it completes successfully, or it returns non-zero on an error.  In your case, "success" could mean "the character was valid" and "error" could mean "the character was invalid".  Making this change should let you eliminate the global variable `value`.  You can also eliminate the global `c` if you pass the input to `check_dig` as a parameter (`c` would become a local variable inside `main()`).

I recommend that you only use the `check_dig` function to *check* the digit, and that you remove the part that reads another character.  You should make the decision whether or not to skip a character before calling `check_dig`.  That way, you can separate your "read" code, your "skip" code, and your "check" code.  This makes your program easier to read and debug.

Comment: Thanks that helped alot and I understand using the return values etc, except for the return on the main? I've now got seperate functions for check_digit check_comma and skip_char but i'm wondering how I then use the return value of main from this?